# jQuery validate and collections of minimum length

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a property

```
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Must map at least 1 component.")]
    [Required]
    public Thingy[] Thingys { get; set; }
```

that is rendered to the view like

```
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Thingys, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <tbody>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Thingys.Length; ++i)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @(Model.Thingys[i].State)
                        @Html.Hidden("Thingys[" + @i + "].State", Model.Thingys[i].State, new { @class= "form-control thingy-state" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @(Model.Thingys[i].Id)
                        @Html.Hidden("Thingys[" + @i + "].Id", Model.Thingys[i].Id, new { @class = "form-control thingy-id" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @(Model.Thingys[i].Name)
                        @Html.Hidden("Thingys[" + @i + "].Name", Thingys.Components[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control thingy-name" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

and I expect it to get picked up by jQuery validate if there are no rows. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: `MinLength` cannot be applied to a collection of complex objects. You will need to write your own script that handles the submit event. but what are you trying to validate anyway - you are generating rows so there will always be rows!. And just use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Thingys[i].State, new { @class = " thingy-state" })` to generate the inputs (not sure what your class names are for, but adding `form-control` to a hidden input makes no sense)

Comment: Are you actually wanting to check if at least one row has the associated checkbox checked?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `MinLength` summary says "Specifies the minimum length of the array or string" .. so I assumed it could be used on an array.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `MinLength` summary says "Specifies the minimum length of the array or string" .. so I assumed it could be used on an array and would create something like `data-min-length="1"` and validate.

Comment: Your not generating an input for the collection (and it would not make sense to do so) so how could a `data-val-*` attribute be applied to the input!

Comment: About the only thing that can reasonably be applied to is say an `int[] SelectedItems` property that is used to bind to a multiple select